# Syntax for while loop in equation in Modelica?

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica

I am trying to implement a simple iterative guessing scheme within the `equation` section in a model, however, I am getting the following error: `No viable alternative near token: while` in OpenModelica. Is there a simple explanation to why this while-loop does not work?

```
while hf>=dh loop
   v_guess = v_guess*0.95;  
   f_guess = Functions.f_Haaland(v=v_guess, D=d, rho=rho, mu=mu, eps=roughness);
   hf = Functions.H_f(f=_guess, L=length, D=d, v=v_guess, g=system.g);
end while;
```

Say,

- hf=11
- dh=10
- v_guess=1

What I want is v_guess to become smaller and smaller until hf is approximately equal to dh. Then I'll use v_guess in the next step of my model because it is close to the real v occurring at dh. I also tried the same with for-loops and break, to no avail.

I'm looking at the syntax for while-loops and it looks exactly similar. Is there any fundamental thing that is wrong with my scheme, which I cannot see?

Comment: What do you have before the "while" keyword?

Comment: Ah, nevernind, you are in an equation section which does not support while loops, only for loops. Make it an algorithm section as Hans below proposes, but then you need to change = to := in the code.

Comment: Hi Adrian. I guess I'll make it into a function then, considering the fact that the code snippet is located in the middle of other code inside the equation section. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modelica has equations and algorithms. Algorithms work similarly as in most languages and allow while-loops.

Equations are **always** valid and unordered so if you write `v_guess = v_guess*0.95;` it means that `v_guess` should always have this value - which only has the solution `v_guess=0` - which is likely not what you want.

You can have for-loops in equations, but that is for handling an array where each element in the array have a separate equation - written compactly.

So, if you want to write a while-loop either write it directly in an algorithm section or hide it in a function.

```
algorithm
 while hf>=dh loop
   v_guess := v_guess*0.95;  
   f_guess := Functions.f_Haaland(v=v_guess, D=d, rho=rho, mu=mu, eps=roughness);
   hf := Functions.H_f(f=_guess, L=length, D=d, v=v_guess, g=system.g);
end while;
```

(Note that it should be `:=` in algorithms and `=` in equations to emphasize this difference, most tools handle both.)

Added:
Note that you can have multiple algorithm-sections in a model, so you can have a few equations, an algorithm section, another algorithm section, and then a few more equations.
The benefit of having multiple algorithm sections is that each section is executed in order, but they can be rearranged freely.

Comment: @Jonas If I read that code correctly, you are doing some kind of rootfinding, by trying ALL possible values. Maybe you can instead use bisection, or the function Modelica.Math.Nonlinear.solveOneNonlinearEquation. This would be faster, and more accurate.

Comment: @matth Thanks for the suggestion. I'm really only trying to find the one value of v_guess which corresponds to the real velocity at pressure loss dh over a pipe. 
The equation is dh=(f/2g)*(L/D)*v^2 (where f and v are unknown). By guessing v, I calculate f(v) and hf(f(v)) until hf=dh. I am unsure if this would work using solveOneNonlinearEquation, as I am not familiar with it. I don't know which upper and lower limit I would use as inputs, and as I mentioned I really only need the last guessed v.